# Unable to manually resize TableView with CollapseRowHeaders/CollapsedColumnHeaders

Tags: display, tableview

I would like to display a table using `TableView`. My table already has headers, so I remove them using `AppearanceElements -> {"CollapsedRowHeaders",  "CollapsedColumnHeaders"}`. When I do so though, the little triangle at the bottom right of `TableView` disappears and I can't resize it manually. I like to have this option so I can adjust the displayed table in `TableView` to the current size of the Notebook window.

As an example, compare:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{1, 100}], 10, 20];
TableView[data,  ImageSize -> 700]
```

and

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{1, 100}], 10, 20];
TableView[data, AppearanceElements -> {"CollapsedRowHeaders","CollapsedColumnHeaders"}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

The question is: **Am I naïve in thinking this should be an option all the time, or is something going wrong with the manual resizing tool when collapsing headers?**

Comment: You'll need to add `"ResizeArea"` to the `AppearanceElements` (when you overwrite the default option value, you effectively removed that part)

Comment: That being said, you could also just set your headers via the `Headers` option, then there might not even be a need to collapse them

Comment: ah wow, I can't believe it's that simple and I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for the headers tip.